# How can I connect to my backend server from my frontend dev server react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack-dev-server, http-proxy-middleware

I am running my node backend on port 8000 and my dev server front end on port 9002. Ive tried a few ways to proxy to my backend when running dev, but all seem to fail (maybe because i also have

`"type": "module"`
)? I have tried http-proxy-middleware, but with no success.

In my server.cjs file, I have an app.get('/properties'....). It retrieves an array of objects with address, city and zip. On postman, running on port 8000, I get the correct response. Additionally, when i run start on port 8000 on my frontend, I also get the correct response. However, when I run on port 9002, my error is http://localhost:9002/properties 404, not found.

For development purposes, I need to be able to work on development, that way I wint have to run build for every UI change I make. Here is some snippets of my code below:

package.json

```
    {
     "name": "properties-three", 
    "version": "1.0.0", 
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js", 
    "type": "module", 
    "proxy": "http://localhost:8000", 
    "scripts": 
    { 
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1", 
        "dev": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.config.cjs", 
        "start": "nodemon --use_strict server.mjs", 
        "build": "webpack --mode production" 
    }, "
    author": "", 
    "license": "ISC", 
    "devDependencies": { 
        "@babel/core": "^7.19.6", 
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.4", 
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
         "babel-loader": "^8.2.5", 
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0", 
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0", 
        "webpack": "^5.74.0",
         "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0" 
    }, 
    "dependencies": { 
        "axios": "^1.1.3", 
        "cors": "^2.8.5", 
        "express": "^4.18.2", 
        "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
        "react": "^18.2.0", 
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2", 
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1" 
    }
     }
```

setupProxy.js

```
     import {createProxyMiddleware} from "http-proxy-middleware";

     module.exports = function(app) {
        app.use(
            '/api/properties',
            createProxyMiddleware({
                target: 'http://localhost:8000',
                changeOrigin: true,
                secure: false,
                ws: true
            })
        );
    };
```

webpack.config.cjs:

```
    const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
    const path = require('path');

    const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
        template: "./src/index.html",
        filename: "./index.html"
    });
    module.exports = {
        entry: "./src/index.js",
        output: { // NEW
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            filename: "bundle.js",
            publicPath: "/"
        }, // NEW Ends
        devServer: {
            port: 9002,
            static: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
            hot: true,
            historyApiFallback: true
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', ".js", ".jsx"],
        },
        mode: "development",
        plugins: [htmlPlugin],
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "babel-loader"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    };
```

server.mjs

```
    import express from 'express';
    import cors from 'cors';
    import path from "path";
    import properties from './routes/properties.routes.js'
    import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

    const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);

    const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

    const app = express();
    const PORT = 8000;

    app.use(express.static(`${process.cwd()}/build`));
    app.use(express.static(`${process.cwd()}/public`));

    app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.json());

    app.use("/properties", properties);

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));


    app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
    });



    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server is running on http://locahost:${PORT}`));
```

App.js

```
    import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
    import axios from "axios";

    function App() {
        const [properties, setProperties] = useState([]);
        useEffect(() =>{
            axios.get('/properties').then((response) =>{
                setProperties(response.data)
            })
        }, []);
        return (
            <div className="App">Test</div>
        );
    }

    export default App;
```

I have tried changing my setupProxy.js to use

```
    import {createProxyMiddleware} from "http-proxy-middleware";
```

instead of

```
    const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
```

I have also tried changing in the component

```
    axios.get('/properties')
```

to

```
    axios.get('/api/properties')
```

Comment: Try to give it a full url including the port: I guess that you're running both the BE and the FE on the same machine on different ports - no?

Comment: Yes, same machine different ports.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the fix. As @NirAlfasi pointed out, I was running the BE and the FE on the same machine. Additionally, my db is currently using mock data stored within my project (for the meantime).

Within my App.js, all I needed to do was create a const baseUrl pointing to my BE port. Then in the get request on the FE, point to that baseUrl, plus the endpoint.

```
const baseURL = 'http://localhost:8000';
```

```
axios.get(`${baseURL}/properties`).then((response)...
```